# How do I delete something from a NumPy array while iterating through it and multiple other arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

I have three lists: "targets", "contexts", and "labels." I'm iterating through the list, and trying to delete rows in the "targets" and the "contexts" lists where the equivalent row in "labels" is a 0. But, when I try to delete the row in my "contexts" list, Numpy complains that whatever's supposed to be in that row doesn't exist.

```
import json
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
assert os.path.isfile("train-v1.1.json"),"Non-existent file"
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
#import keras
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
import re
regex = re.compile(r'\W+')
#Reading the files.
def readFile(filename):
  with open(filename) as file:
    fields = []
    JSON = json.loads(file.read())
    articles = []
    for article in JSON["data"]:
      articleTitle = article["title"]
      article_body = []
      for paragraph in article["paragraphs"]:
        paragraphContext = paragraph["context"]
        article_body.append(paragraphContext)
        for qas in paragraph["qas"]:
          question = qas["question"]
          answer = qas["answers"][0]
          fields.append({"question":question,"answer_text":answer["text"],"answer_start":answer["answer_start"],"paragraph_context":paragraphContext,"article_title":articleTitle})
      article_body = "\\n".join(article_body)
      article = {"title":articleTitle,"body":article_body}
      articles.append(article)
  fields = pd.DataFrame(fields)
  fields["question"] = fields["question"].str.replace(regex," ")
  assert not (fields["question"].str.contains("catalanswhat").any())
  fields["paragraph_context"] = fields["paragraph_context"].str.replace(regex," ")
  fields["answer_text"] = fields["answer_text"].str.replace(regex," ")
  assert not (fields["paragraph_context"].str.contains("catalanswhat").any())
  fields["article_title"] = fields["article_title"].str.replace("_"," ")
  assert not (fields["article_title"].str.contains("catalanswhat").any())
  return fields,JSON["data"]
trainingData,training_JSON = readFile("train-v1.1.json")
print("JSON dataset read.")
#Text preprocessing
## Converting text to skipgrams
print("Tokenizing sentences.")
strings = trainingData.drop("answer_start",axis=1)
strings = strings.values.flatten()
textTokenizer = Tokenizer()
textTokenizer.fit_on_texts(strings)
questionsTokenized_train = pad_sequences(textTokenizer.texts_to_sequences(trainingData["question"]))
print(questionsTokenized_train.shape)
contextTokenized_train = pad_sequences(textTokenizer.texts_to_sequences(trainingData["paragraph_context"]))
print("Sentences tokenized.")
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import *
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import skipgrams,make_sampling_table
def skipgrams_labels(sequence,vocabulary_length,window_size=3):
    try:
        couples,labels = skipgrams(sequence,vocabulary_length,window_size=window_size)
        assert len(couples) > 0
        target_word,context = zip(*couples)
        return np.array([target_word,context,labels]).T
    except Exception as e:
        raise ValueError("Exception in skipgrams_labels")
    def positive_skipgrams(sequence,vocabulary_length,window_size=3):
        targets,contexts,labels = skipgrams_labels(sequence,vocabulary_length,window_size=3)
        for target,context,label in zip(targets,contexts,labels):
            if (label == 0):
                targets = np.delete(targets,target)
                contexts = np.delete(contexts,context)
        return targets,contexts
```

Error:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 question_skipgrams_train = [positive_skipgrams(sequence,vocabulary_length) for sequence in
>   questionsTokenized_train]
>
> in (.0)
>   ----> 1 question_skipgrams_train = [positive_skipgrams(sequence,vocabulary_length) for sequence in
>   questionsTokenized_train]
>
> in positive_skipgrams(sequence,
>   vocabulary_length, window_size)
>         4         if (label == 0):
>         5             targets = np.delete(targets,target)
>   ----> 6             contexts = np.delete(contexts,context)
>         7     return targets,contexts
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py
>   in delete(arr, obj, axis)    4374             raise IndexError(
>   4375                 "index %i is out of bounds for axis %i with "
>   -> 4376                 "size %i" % (obj, axis, N))    4377         if (obj < 0):    4378             obj += N
>
> IndexError: index 44086 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 132

I don't understand why anything's wrong here. This feels like a bit of a weird error, because NumPy must have been able to find the element - else why wouldn't the for loop be the one with an error?

I even replaced the skipgrams_labels function with hardcoded values, indicating something must be wrong with the function.

What do you recommend I do instead?

Comment: Can you show a simpler example with synthetic data, so I'd be able to replicate your code here? Also, I suspect your error is due to index, I mean you are deleting something from your array with size n, and now you have another array with size n-1 but your loop still goes to n. However, this is just a hint, without your data I wouldn't be able to replicate your error.

Comment: I strongly recommend finding somewhere you can get feedback on your entire program (I can take a look if you have a way of sharing it). The variable and function names here are both inconsistent and against Python style conventions. Assert statements should be used for debugging only, not as a normal way to check certain conditions and throw errors. Import statements should be at the top of the file. I salute mikewatt for noticing a problem in the code, because it feels like a brick wall.

Comment: Don't try to delete things iteratively, one at a time.  It is sloe and error prone.  Collect a list (indexes) of what you want to delete, and do the actual deletion once at the end.

Answer (score 1):

The `target` variable in the `for` loop is a value from `targets`, but `np.delete()` is **expecting you to feed it an index** (or slice) to delete.  The current `target` value of 44086 happens to be out of bounds for the `targets` array which only has 132 items on the first axis.

Note the bolded part.  `np.delete()` isn't meant to delete a particular value, it deletes a particular index.

Comment: D'oh! OK, so how do I delete a VALUE?

Comment: @MontanaBurr That's a different question entirely, and one which may be off topic for Stack Overflow, especially due to the likelihood of design issues in the program.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do what I wanted is:

```
targets = targets[labels != 0]
contexts = contexts[labels != 0]
```

Comment: _The correct way to do what I wanted is:_ Eeh, probably not. `np.where()` shouldn’t be used with just the condition parameter. I’ve never used `numpy.delete()`, and I see no reason to here. All you needed is some basic masking, like `targets = targets[targets != 0]`. Have you read the NumPy docs?

Comment: @AMC: Not fully. Thanks for the tip!